# What causes memory leak in this function

Tags: python, sqlite, memory, memory-leaks

## Memory leak

I have this function `volumeCounter()` that is in a loop (in function `looper()`)that executes every 10 sec. It is receiving data via api. After that it stores it into a sqlite database. When ran for a few hours, the ram will rise. It is especially noticeable when there are 100 threads or more of this function running (one thread for each market like BTC-ETH). After commenting it out, memory usage did not rise.

My question is, what inside this function is causing memory to rise.

```
def volumeCounter(self):
    pass_to_table = api.get_market_history(self.market, 100)["result"] #This is in json format.
    for i in pass_to_table:
        id_i = i['Id']
        time_i = i['TimeStamp'].replace("T", " ")
        type_i = i['OrderType']
        total = i['Total']
        price = i["Price"]
        self.cursor.execute(
            """INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {} (id, price, total, type,time) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)""".format(
                self.table_prices), (id_i, price, total, type_i, time_i))
        self.connection.commit()
```

Function `looper()` that is looping `volumeCounter()`. It is executed in `__init__()` at start.
Script looks like this:

```
key = 'public_key'
secret = 'secret_key'
api = Bittrex(key, secret)



class CryptoScanner:
def __init__(self, market, interval, mailAdrr, mailPass, volume):
    # Spremenljivke
    self.market = market
    self.timeInterval = interval
    self.path = "ann{}/{}".format(interval, market)
    self.path_2 = self.market.replace('-', '_')
    self.database = "{}/{}.db".format(self.path, self.path_2)
    self.mailAdrr = mailAdrr
    self.mailPass = mailPass
    self.sez_length = 0
    self.volume = volume
    self.scan_mode = False

    # Table names
    self.table_prices = '{}_prices'.format(self.path_2)
    self.table_prices_sum = '{}_prices_sum'.format(self.path_2)
    self.table_volume = '{}_volume'.format(self.path_2)
    self.table_volume_change = '{}_volume_change'.format(self.path_2)

    self.looper()
```

Then the class object is made for every market with multithreading.

```
for i in api.get_market_summaries()['result']:
    if "BTC" in i['MarketName'] and i['BaseVolume'] >= lower_boundary and i['BaseVolume'] <= upper_boundary:
        string = i['MarketName']
        d["{}".format(string[4:])] = "{}".format(i['MarketName'])
        volume["{}".format(string[4:])] = i['BaseVolume']
threads = []
for i in d:
    t = threading.Thread(target=CryptoScanner, args=(d[i], interval_sec, mail, password, volume[i]))
    threads.append(d)
    t.start()
    print("Created thread {}".format(d[i]))
```

### Edit

Added bittrex api library details

```
class Bittrex(object):
"""
Used for requesting Bittrex with API key and API secret
"""
def __init__(self, api_key, api_secret):
    self.api_key = str(api_key) if api_key is not None else ''
    self.api_secret = str(api_secret) if api_secret is not None else ''

def api_query(self, method, options=None):
    """
    Queries Bittrex with given method and options
    :param method: Query method for getting info
    :type method: str
    :param options: Extra options for query
    :type options: dict
    :return: JSON response from Bittrex
    :rtype : dict
    """
    if not options:
        options = {}
    nonce = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
    method_set = 'public'

    if method in MARKET_SET:
        method_set = 'market'
    elif method in ACCOUNT_SET:
        method_set = 'account'

    request_url = (BASE_URL % method_set) + method + '?'

    if method_set != 'public':
        request_url += 'apikey=' + self.api_key + "&nonce=" + nonce + '&'

    request_url += urlencode(options)

    return requests.get(
        request_url,
        headers={"apisign": hmac.new(self.api_secret.encode(), request_url.encode(), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()}
    ).json()
def get_market_history(self, market, count):
    """
    Used to retrieve the latest trades that have occurred for a
    specific market.
    /market/getmarkethistory
    :param market: String literal for the market (ex: BTC-LTC)
    :type market: str
    :param count: Number between 1-100 for the number of entries to return (default = 20)
    :type count: int
    :return: Market history in JSON
    :rtype : dict
    """
    return self.api_query('getmarkethistory', {'market': market, 'count': count})
```

Comment: what exactly is going on in `api.get_market_history`?

Comment: I am monitoring volume of exchanged crypto coins. You send a request via their api. After that you get data or recent trades.
`get_market_history` is just a function in their library.

Comment: Maybe the memory leak comes from there...

Comment: I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga, can you post your any code or doc references to this `get_market_history` method so we can help troubleshoot?  I know it is a method in their library, but perhaps it wasn't meant to be persistent and needs a `close` statement, or something similar you are missing.

Comment: @sadmicrowave I added the library.

Comment: @Razmooo, next question: what calls `looper()`?  And can you post that block too?  I know you said it's called in `__init__()` at start, but what calls the class?  What I'm looking for is an inadvertent nested loop that continues to spawn more and more loops over time.

Comment: @sadmicrowave added the class and calling of the class.

Comment: @Razmooo, let's keep backtracking here: what calls `for i in api.get_market_summaries()['result']:` and how often does it get called?

Comment: @sadmicrowave it gets called once in the beginning of the script in `if __name__ == '__main__':`. It fills a dictionary with market names. After that it is not called anymore.

Comment: @Razmooo, well I'm stumped, it looks ok from many angles, but obviously there is something not quite right.  Try pasting the link to the question in a python chat room (now that it has been active for several days).